# Show a list of simple products in shopping cart by modifying their item renderer in magento 2

Tags: php, html, xml, magento, shopping-cart

Modify the way configurable products are rendered in the shopping cart by modifying their item renderer.
Show in the line item a list of all simple product names that are assigned to the configurable in the cart.

I have used the following code

> Vendor/ModifyProductsRender/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout_cart_form">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="checkout_cart_item_renderers_override" as="renderer_list_custom"/>
        <arguments>
            <argument name="renderer_list_name" xsi:type="string">checkout_cart_item_renderers_override</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

> Vendor/ModifyProductsRender/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout_cart_item_renderers_override">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="Custom_Addprofile::cart/item/default.phtml" />

        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="Custom_Addprofile::cart/item/default.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

I need to add .phtml file but dont know how to modify renderer.

p.s : I m new to magento

Comment: Consider editing your question to describe the problem that you want to resolve.

Comment: the first three lines is the question

Comment: Editing your question per my suggestion is optional. I made it to help improve the quantity and quality of the answers submitted for your question.